# Why is this first-order ODE considered non-linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology, definition

Consider the following equation: $$y'=\sin y.$$

What causes this equation to be considered non-linear?  $y'$ is not multiplied by a power, and neither is $\sin y$.

Comment: Linear would imply that if $ y$ is a solution then $2y $ is also a solution. But that would imply that $\sin(2y) = 2\sin(y)$, which is usually not the case.  (A homogeneous ODE is "linear" when any linear combination of solutions is also a solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear differential equation is one that has the following form:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x).$$
To see that this doesn't hold in this case, try to convert
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\sin y$$
to the appropriate form. Rearranging we have
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}-(1)\sin y=0.$$
As you can see, this is not linear in $y$. That is, $y$ does not sit on its own with a function of $x$ as its prefactor in the non-differential term.

Comment: So you're saying that in this case

dy/dx = ysin(x) would be linear?

Comment: Yes. Because then we could express this as $$ \frac{dy}{dx}-(\sin x)y=0.$$  Here $p(x)=-(\sin x)$, and $q(x)=0$.

Comment: So overall, if the dependent variable is in a trig function, it is considered non-linear? Thank you for your help and quick replies.

Comment: Yes- that is true. More generally, though, we must be able to put the function in the form above (in my answer). So, even if we had $$ \frac{dy}{dx}-y^2=0$$ this still wouldn't be a linear differential equation. My point is that it is still non-linear if $y$ is "stuck" in any other type of function.

Comment: Okay, this helps a lot. So I am trying to understand your example above, what would p(x) and q(x) stand for?

Comment: Arbitrary functions of $x$. For instance, we could have $$ \frac{dy}{dx}+x^3e^x (y)=\sin x$$ as a linear first order ordinary differential equation. Here $p(x)=x^3 e^x$ and $q(x)=\sin x$.

Comment: Wow, this cleared up so much for me! Thank you for being so patient! :)
So if my understanding of your statement is correct, would

Comment: No problem- good luck!

Comment: Whoop, one final question
So if my understanding of your statement is correct, would dy/dx + x^y = sin(x) be nonlinear since y would be "stuck" as a power of x? I would not be able to isolate the y that is a power.

Comment: That's correct- there's no way to extract the $y$ to get us into the form we want for the linearity condition.

Answer (score 2):

A first-order differential equation is considered linear if it can be written in the form

$$y'+p(x)y=f(x)$$

$y'=\sin y$ can't be written in that format

Answer (score 2):

Because:

$y^\prime = y-\frac{y^3}{6}+\frac{y^5}{120}-\frac{y^7}{5040}+O\left(y^9\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

"Nonlinear" is NOT just a matter of powers or polynomials in y.  sin(y) is itself a "non-linear" function of y.